# Convert number to reversed array of digits?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to convert number to reversed array of digits using the following function.

```
function digitize(n) {
  var num = n.toString();
  var arr = num.split("");
  arr.reverse();
  parseInt(arr);
  return arr;
}
```

But it is not working. What is wrong with this function?

Answer (score 3):

You need a join to the reversed array and return the parsed string.

```js
function digitize(n) {
    var num = n.toString();
    var arr = num.split("");
    return parseInt(arr.join(''), 10);
    // ^^^             ^^^^^^^^^
}

console.log(digitize(2348));
```

For getting a reverse array of digit, you need to return the reversed array.

```js
function digitize(n) {
    var num = n.toString();
    var arr = num.split("");
    return arr.reverse();
}

console.log(digitize(2348));
```

Comment: I believe the OP wants the return value to be an array, not a number.

Comment: then `parseInt(arr);` would not make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your digits from strings to integers. This can be done with `parseInt` or with a unary plus `+`.

```js
function digitize(n) {
  var arr = n.toString().split("").map(function (digit) {
    return +digit;
  });
  return arr;
}

console.log(digitize(12345));
```